# How can I close Google Compute VM terminal window without stopping my process?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am only just getting started with google compute. I'm trying to use google compute for some lengthy process' that I don't want to run on my personal computer. I am opening the browser terminal then starting my process in the background with '&', which could run for a day or so. However if I close the window and open it back up it doesn't seem the process is still there when I use "ps".

I don't have much experience with VM's so apologies if this is elementary, I'm just not sure where to find this information.

Comment: There are a number of programs to keep your session running such as Linux Screen: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/screen-command-in-linux-with-examples/

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with a long running machine learning model training (closing my local terminal session gave me problems). As @John Hanley has mentioned, `screen` is your friend here.

```sh
# Start another terminal window
screen

# Run your commands

# Resume the session after closing your local terminal session
screen -r
```